# Generate specific xml drawable

Tags: android, xml

How can I make such drawable in xml for androd?
I was thinking about using layer-list but it doesn't seem working:

Here is what I got now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="100%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:width="10dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="0%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:width="10dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item>
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:width="10dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </shape>



    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and here is what I need:

[image]

how is it possible to achieve something like this?
Or is there any online generator for such shapes?

Comment: This is not very helpful comment

Comment: layer-list should be worked. Which android version are you testing it ?

Comment: in xml? you will only produce 100s of lines of xml code and the results will be miserable - use a custom `Shape` class instead

Comment: The problem is I need to set it as a background of a Frame layout so it needs to be xml

Comment: of course not, you can use `View#setBackground`

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: you can call `View#setBackground(Drawable dr)` method

Comment: Yes I can, but I wanted to unify my layout with xmls, but I guess there is no such way

Comment: use `databinding` then and some kind of [custom setter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#custom_setters)

Comment: What's wrong in the answers found in the linked duplicate? Either use a white Unicode character for a triangle and the rest is a yellow bg color, or use a LayerList with a triangle over a rectangle.

Comment: I did it with a png drawable

Comment: ... which is the easiest, but heaviest solution...

Comment: At least, among those solutions which do not use Java. Which would be even worse.

Comment: @ModularSynth what would be worse? java or those xml workarounds with layer-list, rotate etc?

Comment: Java. Because it's not handled natively.

Comment: @ModularSynth i beg your pardon? everything you do in xml is then `draw()`n by one of `android.graphics.drawable.Drawable` - see `LayerDrawable`, `RotateDrawable` etc